# Barcode Scanner Character by Character

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

Ive been trying a while and cant work out a way to get the text out of a textbox only after the barcode scanner has finished scanning. I am using Swing Framework and Java. My Code works if the text is pasted (Ctrl + V) into the JTextbox but the barcode scanner just does not work as my methods run for every couple of characters of the barcode in turn.

Here is my code:

```
public class pos extends javax.swing.JFrame{
private Timer updateTimer;
private ResultSet data;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;

public pos() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Function f = new Function();

            updateTimer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                ResultSet rs = null;
                rs = f.find(prodID.getText());
                data = rs;
                }
            });
            updateTimer.setRepeats(false);

    prodID.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0){
            warn();
        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0){ 
            warn();
        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0){
            warn();
        }          

    });


}

protected void warn(){
            try{
                if(this.data.next()){
                    prodName.setText(this.data.getString("prodName"));
                    priceField.setText(String.valueOf(new Double(this.data.getString("price"))));
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data for this ID");
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
            updateTimer.restart();
        }

public Connection getConnection(){
    Connection con = null;
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fmgaccount","root","");
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
    return con;
}



public class Function{
    Connection con = null;
    public ResultSet find(String s){
        try{
        con = getConnection();
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT prodName, price FROM deliverystocks WHERE prodID=?");
        pst.setString(1,s);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }
         return rs;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: You need a button to "process" the data that is entered into the text field. You will never know if the user is going to type more text or the scanner will scan more text, so you need to user to click the button to indicate the text has been entered so processing can continue. Or maybe the text has a fixed size, in which case you just check the length of the text and automatically to the process when the proper length text has been entered.